# How long does it take to correct the Zertifikat Deutsch exam?

Tags: proficiency-test

If i do the Zertifikat Deutsch Prüfung, how long does it take till I get the results of the exam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the instituition you take the test at. [Goethe-Institut Ungarn, for example](https://www.goethe.de/ins/hu/de/spr/prf/inf.html) says three weeks after the written exam until you know your grades and 30 days for getting the printed exam result, [Carl Duisberg](http://www.carl-duisberg-deutschkurse.de/index.php?id=2330) says one month but you can pay additional 150€ at the registration to get your printed exam result two weeks after the written exam.